# how to select all element that has an attribute of id using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

how can i choose all the elements that has an attribute of id ?? thanks

```
  <article docsubtype="rev" version="5.2" xml:lang="en" xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-bib/dtd" xmlns:sa="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-aff/dtd" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <item-info>
            <jid>APPET</jid>
            <aid>2303</aid>
            <ce:pii>S0195-6663(14)00474-7</ce:pii>
            <ce:doi>10.1016/j.appet.2014.10.004</ce:doi>
            <ce:copyright type="full-transfer" year="2014">Elsevier Ltd</ce:copyright>
            <ce:copyright-line>© 2014 Elsevier Ltd. All rights reserved.</ce:copyright-line><!--<x title="Appetite"/>--><!--<x issn="0195-6663"/>--><!--<x volume="&#x25A0;&#x25A0;"/>--><!--<x coverYear="2014"/>--><!--<x type="authorsRunningHead">E.M. Forman, M.L. Butryn</x>-->
        </item-info>
        <ce:floats>
            <ce:figure id="f0010">
                <ce:label>Fig. 1<!--<x>.&#x2002;</x>--></ce:label>
                <ce:caption id="ca0010">
                    <ce:simple-para id="sp0020">Conceptual model of weight gain and overweight.</ce:simple-para>
                </ce:caption>
                <ce:link id="ln0010" locator="appet2303-fig-0001"/>
            </ce:figure>
            <ce:table frame="topbot" id="t0010">
                <ce:label>Table 1<!--<x> </x>--></ce:label>
                <ce:caption id="ca0015">
                    <ce:simple-para id="sp0025">Commonalities of, and distinctions between, standard behavioral interventions and acceptance-based behavioral treatment.</ce:simple-para>
                </ce:caption>
                <tgroup cols="4">
                    <colspec colname="col1" colnum="1"/>
                    <colspec colname="col2" colnum="2"/>
                    <colspec colname="col3" colnum="3"/>
                    <colspec colname="col4" colnum="4"/>
                    <thead>
                        <row>
                            <entry>Domain</entry>
                            <entry>Example components common to both standard behavioral treatment and ABT</entry>
                            <entry>Example components unique to or more strongly emphasized in ABT</entry>
                            <entry>Example components unique to or more strongly emphasized in standard behavioral treatment</entry>
                        </row>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <row>
                            <entry>Psychoeducation</entry>
                            <entry>
                                <ce:list id="ulist0015">
                                    <ce:list-item id="u0040">
                                        <ce:label>•<!--<x>&#x2002;</x>--></ce:label>
                                        <ce:para id="p0190">Nutritional information and guidelines regarding calorie intake</ce:para>
                                    </ce:list-item>
                                    <ce:list-item id="u0045">
                                        <ce:label>•<!--<x>&#x2002;</x>--></ce:label>
                                        <ce:para id="p0195">Additional tools for meeting dietary goals, such as limiting fat intake or portion control</ce:para>
                                    </ce:list-item>
                                    <ce:list-item id="u0050">
                                        <ce:label>•<!--<x>&#x2002;</x>--></ce:label>
                                        <ce:para id="p0200">Guidelines for physical activity</ce:para>
                                    </ce:list-item>
                                    <ce:list-item id="u0055">
                                        <ce:label>•<!--<x>&#x2002;</x>--></ce:label>
                                        <ce:para id="p0205">Obesogenic environment as a challenge to weight loss</ce:para>
                                    </ce:list-item>
                                </ce:list>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <ce:list id="ulist0020">
                                    <ce:list-item id="u0060">
                                        <ce:label>•<!--<x>&#x2002;</x>--></ce:label>
                                        <ce:para id="p0210">Psychoeducation relating to the mind's response to fatty, salty, sweet foods and exertion</ce:para>
                                    </ce:list-item>
                                    <ce:list-item id="u0065">
                                        <ce:label>•<!--<x>&#x2002;</x>--></ce:label>
                                        <ce:para id="p0215">The impossibility of fully controlling internal responses</ce:para>
                                    </ce:list-item>
                                </ce:list>
                            </entry>
```

Comment: Kindly post you xml, tried xslt

Comment: A very unhelpful question I'm afraid. You do not show any of your attempted XLST code, your input XML is incomplete and thus malformed, you do not say what you mean by "choosing" and finally, you tagged the question with both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 - which makes no sense.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usually, it is done with an XPath such as `<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@id]" />`

The `*` will match any element and the `[@id]` predicate will allow to retrieve only the elements having an "id" attribute that has been specified.

Comment: As I see it, we have no idea what the OP meant by "choosing elements that have an `id` attribute". The `apply-templates` itself does not select elements in any way, it just hands those nodes to the XSLT processor and prompts it to find template rules for those elements. Perhaps the OP meant `<xsl:template match="*[@id]">`?